# Trouble with SQL exercise

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the full name (concatenated and with a column header), job title, department id, department name and salary for all employees from the database and nothing I try seems to work.

```
select first_name ||' '|| last_name "Full Name", department_id, salary from employees
```

This is as far as I got since the department_name is from the departments table and the job_title is from the jobs table. The rest is from the employees table and that's why this part works. can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this supposed to be MySQL and *not* SQL Server?

Comment: i am using oracle application express. i am not even sure whats the difference. i think its MySQL though

Comment: If you don't even know what database you are using, how can you expect people to help you?

Comment: I am very new to this, sorry. How can i find out what database i am using?

Comment: How can you not know what database you are using? If this is for a class or some online examply surely you talked about using Oracle, MySql or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp and search for "Alias Example for Tables"

Answer (score -1):

select employees.first_name, employees.last_name, jobs.job_title, departments.department_name, employees.department_id
from employees, jobs, departments
where employees.job_id = jobs.job_id and employees.department_id = departments.department_id

its working now thank you !